# What should be the value of @ModelAttribute when handling POST in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, post, modelattribute

I'm learning Spring MVC with the tutorial of [the site here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/)

My question is basically in the code fragment bellow.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("contact")
                        Contact contact, BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println("First Name:" + contact.getFirstname() + 
                "Last Name:" + contact.getLastname());

    return "redirect:contacts.html";
}
```

- What should the value of **@ModelAttribute** be when just handling a POST request from a form submit?
- Or in other words, what exactly does the **"contact"** value refers to in this situation?

The posted form is defined as follows:

```
<form:form method="post" action="addContact.html">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstname">First Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastname">Last Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastname">Email</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastname">Telephone</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</form:form>
```

Comment: [Have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700804/what-is-the-meaning-of-modelattribute-annotation-at-method-argument-level)

Comment: @Bart Yes I've read that answer before, but I still don't get what the **contact** value mean here. To be more concise, I don't understand when was this **contact** put into the map of Model Attribute. There's no evidence of that value in the definition of the form, does that mean that I can actually use any thing for that value?